# Python function to calculatate a new column using values from other columns in the dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
OrderID     Status      Amount     Item
 1000        complete     10       Item A
 1000        complete      7       Item B
 1000        refund      -10       Item A
 1000        refund       -7       Item B
 1001        complete      8       Item A
 1002        complete      6       Item A
```

I want to calculate *#NetOrders* (2 orders), *NetAmount* (14) and, maybe, *AvgOrderValue* (14/2=7). One option would be to create an additional column (*Orders_count*) that counts the number of unique combinations "OrderID - Status", separately for values "complete" and "refund". Something like this:

```
OrderID     Status      Amount     Item       Orders_count
 1000        complete     10       Item A       1
 1000        complete      7       Item B       0
 1000        refund      -10       Item A      -1
 1000        refund       -7       Item B       0
 1001        complete      8       Item A       1
 1002        complete      6       Item A       1
```

Solutions that would solve the problem:

1. a function that adds this new series (*Orders_count*) to the dataframe
2. a function that summarizes the initial data by returning *(2, 14)* or even *(2, 14, 7)*, meaning 2 net orders, 14 net amount and 7 AOV.

I tried the below direct approach, which makes use of the `duplicated` method of the pandas' dataframe and managed to solve the first problem. However, I would have preferred a more elegant approach, using a function.

A. Create boolean values, separately for "refund" and "complete" orders:

```
mask_refund = df['Status'] =='refund'
df.loc[mask_refund, 'Orders_count'] = df.loc[mask_refund].duplicated(['Status', 'OrderID'])
df.loc[~mask_refund, 'Orders_count'] = df.loc[~mask_refund].duplicated(['Status', 'OrderID'])
```

B. Create a function which transforms the "refund" orders into negative values and, then, apply it on the Series:

```
def bool_to_int(bol, status):
    if bol == False:
        if status == 'COMPLETE':
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
    else:
        return 0

df['Orders_count'] = map(bool_to_int, df['Orders_count'], df['OrderStatus'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am focusing on your sample data and your question

*I want to calculate #NetOrders (2 orders), NetAmount (14) and, maybe, AvgOrderValue (14/2=7).*

```
gp = df[['OrderID','Amount']].groupby('OrderID').sum()
gp = gp[gp['Amount']!=0]

print "#NetOrders: " + str(len(gp.index)) # it is grouped so therfore unique
print "NetAmount: " + str(gp.sum()[0]) #sum up to a single value series and return value 
print "AvgOrderValue: " + str(gp.sum()[0]/len(gp.index)) #compute average

# you'll get 2 of the 3 from this.
gp.describe()
```